# How to multiply these two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Let $\mathbf{A}=[a_{ij}]$ be a matrix of size $n\times n$. Let there be a Vandermonde matrix $\mathbf{V}=v_j^{i-1}$. Let $\mathbf{C}=\mathbf{A}V^{1/2}$.If I want to calculate the determinant of  $\mathbf{C}$, how can I express its elements $c_{ij}$?? 
Please note that I have to perform integration on each of these elements and then calculate the final determinant. So I am looking for an expression for  $c_{ij}$.

Comment: $\det C = \det A \cdot \sqrt{\det V}$.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I need to perform further integration on each element of $\mathbf{C}$. So rather than the final expression for the determinant, I am interested in each element $c_{ij}$.

Comment: How do you want to define $V^{1/2}$? There are many ways to do that.

Comment: I don't know how to calculate fractional power of a mateix or determinant.

Comment: You need to give more detail. What is the context? Where is the problem coming from? What kind of integration? What do you know about $A$?

Comment: This problem comes from the asymptotic expression of hypergeometric function of matrix argument $_pF_q(a_1,\cdots,a_p;b_1,\cdots,b_q;X;Y)$ given in R J Muirhead book of An aspect of Multivariate Statistical Theory. He has expressed this expansion foe p=q=1. The expression is a function of product of fractional power of Vandermonde Mateix and another complicated matrix. I want to perform integration on this expression to find the marginal density function of eugenvalues expressed in the book.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22436/discussion-between-user146290-and-hans-engler).